# why does $\lim_{s \to t} P(|L(t)-L(s)|>\epsilon) =0 \implies \Delta L(t)=0$ P.as

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, levy-processes

Given that a a Levy process $L=L(t)_{0 \leq t \leq T}$ is stochastic continuous i.e 
$\forall t $ and $\forall \epsilon>0$ we have that 
 $$\lim_{s \to t} P(|L(t)-L(s)|>\epsilon) =0$$

then my classnotes on computational finance claim that it is clear that $\Delta L(t)=0$ P-a.s
where $\Delta L(t)=L(t)-L(t_{-}$ where $L(t_{-})=\lim_{s\uparrow t} L(s)$ from the left(Please note that L(t) is a levy process and therefore cadlag). It says this is obviously true but it is far from obvious. Any hints on how could i show this?
My attempt:

Could I just say that 
\begin{align}
&P(|\Delta L(t)|\leq\epsilon )=P(|L(t)-L(t_{-})|\leq\epsilon)=P(|L(t)-\lim_{s \uparrow t}L(s)|\leq\epsilon)=\\
&\qquad=\lim_{s\uparrow t}P(|L(t)-\lim_{s \uparrow t}L(s)|\leq\epsilon)=1-\lim_{s\uparrow t}P(|L(t)-\lim_{s \uparrow t}L(s)|>\epsilon)=\\
&\qquad=1-\lim_{s\to t}P(|L(t)-\lim_{s \uparrow t}L(s)|>\epsilon)=1-0=1
\end{align}

The last equality follows from the definition of stochastic continuity and it implies that $P(\Delta L(t))=0$ P.as as $\epsilon$ can be as small as we want.

This to me looks like a fake forced proof . Could someone show me how to prove this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you conclude that

$$\lim_{s \uparrow t} \mathbb{P} \left( \left|L_t- \lim_{s \uparrow t} L_s \right|>\epsilon \right)=0$$

...? What we *do* know is that

$$\lim_{s \uparrow t} \mathbb{P}(|L_t-L_s|\epsilon) = 0,$$

but that's something totally different.

---

Since $(L_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is right-continuous with left lomits, we have $L_{t-} = \lim_{s \uparrow t} L_s$ almost surely; hence, in particular $L_{t-} = \lim_{s \uparrow t} L_s$ in probability. On the other hand, the identity

$$\lim_{s \uparrow t} \mathbb{P}(|L_t-L_s|>\epsilon)=0 \qquad \text{for all $\epsilon>0$}$$

shows that $\lim_{s \uparrow t} L_s = L_t$ in probability. Now it follows from the uniqueness of the limit that $L_t = L_{t-}$ almost surely. This implies $\Delta L_t=0$ almost surely.

Comment: Actually I knew my solution didnt make any sense but I could not think of a valid argument .  Thank you so much for the answer, you are very kind and helpful and for that I am very grateful.I had been struggling to prove this obvious statement.

Comment: I don't see why $L_t=L_{t-}$ holds almost surely. I mean the uniqueness argument you made to conclude $L_t=L_{t-}$ is unclear . How does $\lim_{s \uparrow t}L_s=L_{t-}$ and $\lim_{s \uparrow t}L_s=L_{t}$ in probability lead to almost sure equality. I mean this is not the standard limit we use in calculus. I mean $\lim_{s \uparrow t}L_s=L_{t} \implies \lim_{s \uparrow t}P(|L_t-L_s|> \epsilon)=0 \forall \epsilon>0 $. When you say that the limit  holds in probability it is not the same limit definition we use in standard calculus. I

Comment: @user3503589 Suppose that $(X_n)_n$ is a sequence of random variables such that $X_n \to X$ in probability and $X_n \to Y$ in probability. Then $X=Y$ almost surely. That's exactly what I use here.